# My Page Won't Scroll Down

Tags: html, css

My website page won't scroll down. There isn't a problem with my HTML (as I have checked through it and could not find anything wrong with it) so attached is my css. Thanks, all your help is appreciated.

```
 body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}



/*HOME*/

#navtop {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 100%;
}

#navtop > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 5%;
    margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

#navtop > ul > li {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0.9em;
    margin-bottom: 0.9em;
    padding: 0.6em 1.5em;
    border-right: solid #9b9b9b 0.15em;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#navtop > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9b9b9b;

}




#navtop .rightmost {
    border: 0;
}


#intro {
    background-image: url("HTC Vive.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-attachment: fixed; 
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#introCover {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: rgba(20,40,45,0.8);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.centered {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 230%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}

.mainTitle {
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #29A5AF;
}

#learn {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20%;
    padding-top: 0;

}

.sub {
    font-size: 215%;
}

#learn p, .sub{
    font-weight: 300;
}

#return {
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #9b9b9b;

}




/* Our Product */

#survey {
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#list {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: bold;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the `body { overflow: hidden }`